# View HTTPS page with WebView in Mac OS X application

Tags: objective-c, macos, oauth, https, webkit

I'm trying to use the implicit authentication of the StackExchange API, and therefor I need to send the user to `https://www.stackexchange.com/oauth?client_id=...&scope=...&redirect_uri=...` (with actual values instead of '...'). Easy, just drag out a WebView in Interface Builder and implement `-webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` from the `WebFrameLoadDelegate` protocol to track if we are at the `redirect_uri` already. *That* works exactly as I want it to. But the WebView internals don't. An error page from `stackexchange.com/oauth`:

> ## Application Login Failure
>
> An error occurred while login into an application.
>
> **Error Details:**
>
> error: invalid_request
> error description: OAuth request must be over HTTPS

But I started the URL with `https://`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSString *oauthAddress = @"https://www.stackexchange.com/oauth?client_id=...&scope=...&redirect_uri=...";
    [loginWebView setMainFrameURL:oauthAddress];
}
```

I can't find any source that says you have to do something else to enable HTTPS on a standard WebView.

It is caused by the WebView internals: in `-webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` I `NSLog()`' the current URL:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)webFrame {
    NSString *currentURL = [[[[webFrame dataSource] request] URL] absoluteString];
    
    NSLog(@"-webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:");
    NSLog(@"Current URL: %@", currentURL);
    
    if ([currentURL hasPrefix:@"https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success"]) {
        NSLog(@"We did login!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2013-03-05 15:31:55.493 MacOverflow[2164:a0f] -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:
2013-03-05 15:31:55.495 MacOverflow[2164:a0f] Current URL: http://stackexchange.com/oauth?client_id=...scope=...&redirect_uri=...
```

**What the?!** WebKit removed the 's' from the protocol part of the URL! How to stop WebKit from doing so? I searched Apple's documentation on WebView (with Cmd+f) for 'https' (0 matches), 'ssl' (0 matches) and even 'secure' (again 0 matches). I'm kinda stuck here, but it must be possible. It would be ridiculous to provide such a sophisticated browser control, but force the developer to write a copy for supporting `https` (which is quite common nowadays IMO)!

**How to make an HTTPS request using WebKit's WebView?**

Comment: This seems not to be related to Webkit but rather to stack exchange.
It works fine with any other sites (tried it with facebook and checked the URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to WebKit.
Remove www. from your URL like so `https://stackexchange.com/oauth` and you should be fine. At least that works for me.